# Detect duplicated groups with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table with a Date field and I would like to detect days where data is not duplicated. Let's imagine the data is like the following:

```
Day        Code Value
01/03/2020  A   10
01/03/2020  B   15
01/03/2020  C   20
02/03/2020  A   10
02/03/2020  B   15
02/03/2020  C   20
03/03/2020  A   10
03/03/2020  B   20
03/03/2020  C   20
04/03/2020  A   10
04/03/2020  B   15
```

I would like to group the data by days. In the example, day 02/03/2020 is the same than 01/03/2020. However, in day 03/03/2020 the value of B has changed. Also, in day 04/03/2020 code C has dissapeared.

The first approach I see is to loop through the data filtering the dataset by day (a) and compare the result with the slice of the day before (b) by checking if `a.equals(b)` is `TRUE`. I know this works but it is not efficient at all as implies a lot of slicing.

Is there any `group_by` operation that could do the task?

Thank you very much.

Comment: can you add the expected output as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this is one way to drop duplicate days, i.e., days whose (`Code`, `Value`) pairs exactly match those of some other day.

```
unstacked = df.set_index(['Day', 'Code']).unstack()
unstacked
           Value            
Code           A     B     C
Day                         
01/03/2020  10.0  15.0  20.0
02/03/2020  10.0  15.0  20.0
03/03/2020  10.0  20.0  20.0
04/03/2020  10.0  15.0   NaN

res = unstacked.drop_duplicates().stack().reset_index()               
res['Value'] = res['Value'].astype(int)
res
          Day Code  Value
0  01/03/2020    A     10
1  01/03/2020    B     15
2  01/03/2020    C     20
3  03/03/2020    A     10
4  03/03/2020    B     20
5  03/03/2020    C     20
6  04/03/2020    A     10
7  04/03/2020    B     15
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works great and it is very simple too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `GroupBy.agg` then remove the duplicates with `duplicated`:

```
dups = df.astype(str).groupby('Day').agg(''.join).duplicated()
df[~df['Day'].map(dups)]

           Day Code  Value
0   01/03/2020    A     10
1   01/03/2020    B     15
2   01/03/2020    C     20
6   03/03/2020    A     10
7   03/03/2020    B     20
8   03/03/2020    C     20
9   04/03/2020    A     10
10  04/03/2020    B     15
```

Comment: Thank you for your approach. It works great too. I find it a bit less intuitive than Peter's suggestion but works perfectly as well. Thank you!